# formatting data for 5 years for each month with year hyphen javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this kind of data

```
[  {
    "camera_name": "Bolands Mills Arup",
    "exid": "bolands-mills-arup",
    "latest_snapshot_date": "2019-05-30T07:06:55+01:00",
    "oldest_snapshot_date": "2015-12-24T23:33:23+00:00",
    "years": {
      "2015": [
        "12"
      ],
      "2016": [
        "04",
        "08",
        "09",
        "10",
        "02",
        "06",
        "03",
        "11",
        "12",
        "01",
        "07",
        "05"
      ],
      "2017": [
        "04",
        "07",
        "10",
        "09",
        "11",
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "05",
        "06",
        "08",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2018": [
        "03",
        "05",
        "06",
        "10",
        "11",
        "01",
        "02",
        "08",
        "09",
        "04",
        "07",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2019": [
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "04",
        "05"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "camera_name": "Walls Demo",
    "exid": "central-bank-fusion",
    "latest_snapshot_date": "2019-05-30T07:07:02+01:00",
    "oldest_snapshot_date": "2015-11-08T16:30:48+00:00",
    "years": {
      "2015": [
        "12",
        "11"
      ],
      "2016": [
        "02",
        "03",
        "05"
      ],
      "2017": [
        "03",
        "08",
        "10",
        "02",
        "04",
        "05",
        "06",
        "07",
        "09",
        "11",
        "01",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2018": [
        "03",
        "04",
        "07",
        "09",
        "01",
        "02",
        "08",
        "10",
        "11",
        "05",
        "06",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2019": [
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "04",
        "05"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

At first, I was trying to format this data with year value, and it was resulting in this.

```
[
  {
    "camera_name": "Bolands Mills Arup",
    "exid": "bolands-mills-arup",
    "latest_snapshot_date": "2019-05-30T07:06:55+01:00",
    "oldest_snapshot_date": "2015-12-24T23:33:23+00:00",
    "oct": 1,
    "nov": 1,
    "dec": 1,
    "jan": 1,
    "feb": 1,
    "mar": 1,
    "apr": 1,
    "may": 1,
    "jun": 1,
    "jul": 1,
    "aug": 1,
    "sep": 1
  },
  {
    "camera_name": "Walls Demo",
    "exid": "central-bank-fusion",
    "latest_snapshot_date": "2019-05-30T07:07:02+01:00",
    "oldest_snapshot_date": "2015-11-08T16:30:48+00:00",
    "oct": 0,
    "nov": 0,
    "dec": 0,
    "jan": 0,
    "feb": 1,
    "mar": 1,
    "apr": 0,
    "may": 1,
    "jun": 0,
    "jul": 0,
    "aug": 0,
    "sep": 0
  }
]
```

This was when a user was selecting only one year, for example, 2016. then the above results will be generated, Right now I am trying to formulate this data such as.

```
{
    "camera_name": "Walls Demo",
    "exid": "central-bank-fusion",
    "latest_snapshot_date": "2019-05-30T07:07:02+01:00",
    "oldest_snapshot_date": "2015-11-08T16:30:48+00:00",
    "2015-jan": 0,
    "2015-feb": 0,
    ....
    "2015-nov": 1,
    "2015-dec": 1,
    "2016-jan": 0,
    "2016-feb": 1,
    so on ...
  }
```

there are going to be approximately 60 columns for 5 year's 12 months.

this is the method I am using to make data which is shown in 2nd pattern

```
formatDataWithYear(cameras) {
  let months_chars = {
    "01":"jan", 
    "02":"feb", 
    "03":"mar",
    "04":"apr",
    "05":"may",
    "06":"jun",
    "07":"jul",
    "08":"aug",
    "09":"sep",
    "10":"oct",
    "11":"nov",
    "12":"dec"
  }
  let year = this.year;
  var obj = cameras.map(({years, ...obj}) => {
    var months = years[year]
    for(var i in months_chars) {
      months.includes(i) ? obj[months_chars[i]] = 1 : obj[months_chars[i]] = 0
    }
    return obj
  });
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include all years, you could run an additional loop like so:

```
  var obj = cameras.map(({years, ...obj}) => {
      for(var year in years) {
          var months = years[year];
          for(var i in months_chars) {
              months.includes(i) ? obj[year + "-" + months_chars[i]] = 1 : obj[year + "-" + months_chars[i]] = 0
          }
      }
      return obj;
  });
```

Comment: I want to inclue all years not one year the past code was for one year only question is to add allyears now

Comment: Yes, it works, but you should verify that for yourself :)

Comment: I am getting an error on `months.includes(i) ? obj[months_chars[i]] = 1 : obj[months_chars[i]] = 0` 
Also can you please handle one thing? when like its `"2015": []` there is nothing in this?

Comment: Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/juliansmithies/pen/EzrYRo for you to have a look at. 

Notice that the line you're getting an error on has been changed, and you no longer need `let year = this.year` as `year` is defined in the outer loop.

Comment: I mam sorry it was my bad. your code is fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using `Object.entries` will help us map over the values much easier:

```js
const cameras = [{
    "camera_name": "Bolands Mills Arup",
    "exid": "bolands-mills-arup",
    "latest_snapshot_date": "2019-05-30T07:06:55+01:00",
    "oldest_snapshot_date": "2015-12-24T23:33:23+00:00",
    "years": {
      "2015": [
        "12"
      ],
      "2016": [
        "04",
        "08",
        "09",
        "10",
        "02",
        "06",
        "03",
        "11",
        "12",
        "01",
        "07",
        "05"
      ],
      "2017": [
        "04",
        "07",
        "10",
        "09",
        "11",
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "05",
        "06",
        "08",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2018": [
        "03",
        "05",
        "06",
        "10",
        "11",
        "01",
        "02",
        "08",
        "09",
        "04",
        "07",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2019": [
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "04",
        "05"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "camera_name": "Walls Demo",
    "exid": "central-bank-fusion",
    "latest_snapshot_date": "2019-05-30T07:07:02+01:00",
    "oldest_snapshot_date": "2015-11-08T16:30:48+00:00",
    "years": {
      "2015": [
        "12",
        "11"
      ],
      "2016": [
        "02",
        "03",
        "05"
      ],
      "2017": [
        "03",
        "08",
        "10",
        "02",
        "04",
        "05",
        "06",
        "07",
        "09",
        "11",
        "01",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2018": [
        "03",
        "04",
        "07",
        "09",
        "01",
        "02",
        "08",
        "10",
        "11",
        "05",
        "06",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2019": [
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "04",
        "05"
      ]
    }
  }
]

let months_chars = {
  "01": "jan",
  "02": "feb",
  "03": "mar",
  "04": "apr",
  "05": "may",
  "06": "jun",
  "07": "jul",
  "08": "aug",
  "09": "sep",
  "10": "oct",
  "11": "nov",
  "12": "dec"
}

// Map over every camera object in the array,
// and deconstruct the object to give us the years, and the rest of the object.
var obj = cameras.map(({years, ...obj}) => {
  // Loop over each entry from the years object,
  // and deconstruct the array into a key/value pair:
  // e.g. [year, months] => 2016, [01,02,03] etc
  Object.entries(years).forEach(([year, months]) => {
    // Then loop over each entry in the months_chars object,
    // and deconstruct the array into another key/value pair:
    // e.g. [key, month] => 01, "jan"
    Object.entries(months_chars).forEach(([key, month]) => {
      // Check if the months value from earlier has the specified month,
      // and set the objects's value to 1 or 0 accordingly
      obj[`${year}-${month}`] = months.includes(key) ? 1 : 0
    })
  })
  return obj
})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: will this work when there is no single month in year? like `"2015": []`

Comment: Yes. It will check if the value is in the array. If the array is empty (meaning it doesn't have the value) it will return 0